Equations that look good in 1- and 2-columns layout
This is a common issue, and while similar questions may have been asked here, I couldn’t find an exact match for my situation.
My challenge arises from the formatting of my notes and manuscripts. I typically write my notes in a single-column layout, which aligns with the "preprint" format that many journals accept. However, to preview how the final published version will look, I often switch to a two-column layout. This switch requires substantial reformatting, especially with equations—breaking them up using environments like align or multline.
Conversely, when I start with a two-column layout and need to revert to a single-column format (e.g., for notes), the equations formatted for two columns often look too narrow in the wider layout, and I have to manually adjust them back.
I’m looking for a way to streamline this process. Is there an environment or approach that adapts well to both single-column and two-column layouts, reducing the need for repetitive reformatting?

This was one of the aims of breqn to enable automatic reflow of equations to fit the available width, but it doesn't really work to make publication alignments, so basically you do need to do it by hand.

@DavidCarlisle I understand that there is no fully automatic solution, and I am ready, e.g., to remove/insert "\" in proper places. But multline looks ugly in one line, whereas for align breakpoints need to be manually removed/inserted. These two points take unnecessary time, and, therefore,  I want to streamline the process.

Yes I understand that's what you want, but I'd say for publication quality documents you can not have what you want. You may think that having to code the equation twice with different alignment and break points takes time, but previous generations had to make those choices with lead fonts, which took a lot longer. Compared to the time taken to do the mathematics and write the paper, it's not so bad.

@DavidCarlisle Nice argument, it is not so bad indeed.
